# Truncate specific files

Tags: batch-file

I have several folders withing the same directory that are named like that :

```
001_Trial1
002_Trial2
003_Trial3
Trial4
Trial5
004_Trial6
005_Trial7
```

etc ...

I want to rename the folders in order to get

```
Trial1
Trial2
Trial3
Trial4
Trial5
Trial6
```

etc...

I tried to truncate it but the problem is that it will also delete the four first characters when the folder is "Trial3" it will rename it "3".

```
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /D %%A In ("%1\*") Do (

    Set "_d=%%~nxA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not Exist "%%~dpA!_d:~4!" Ren "%%A" "!_d:~4!"
    EndLocal
)
```

I want all the outputs to start with "Trial"

Comment: (Untested) Try `"%1\*_*"` in your `for` command to only pick directories with underscores in them.

Comment: I'd use a `for /F` loop rather than stripping off a fixed number of characters: `pushd "%~1" && ((for /F "tokens=1* delims=_ eol=_" %%E in ('dir /B /A:D') do if not "%%F" == "" ren "%%E_%%F" "%%F") & popd)`...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed looking at your code is, that you need to replace `%1` with `%~1` to get rid of the quotes.

I would then use a `for /f` to cut off the first part of your folder-names, so you don't need delayedExpansion and the code can handle folder-names with more or less digits at the beginning (and of course does not rename folders that already have the wanted name-format).

```
for /D %%D in ("%~1\*") do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%N in ("%%~nD") do (
        if not exist "%%~dpD%%~N%%~xD" ren "%%~fD" "%%~N%%~xD"
    )
)
```